# Configuring multiple users on multiple pcs

Tags: windows-server-2012, deployment, credentials

I need to create the same 60 user profiles on 30 pcs with Windows 7. They will connect to a windows server 2012. Is there a fast way to deploy profiles on all the computers quickly? First step would be of course creating users and rights in Windows server. Then?

Comment: Why are you not using roaming profiles?  If you used roaming profiles it wouldn't matter what PC you logged into, the user's individual configurations, would be migrated.

Comment: Last time I have created some users it was on a Windows server 2003! Did I forgot something?

Comment: What exactly is your follow-up question?  If you don't know what or how roaming profiles work, have you performed research, if so you should clarify your question.

Comment: If I am not wrong I recall that roaming profile was very slow to access and once the server connection was unavailable you could wait five minutes before connecting and then fall down on a temporary desktop/user environment. Still the same in WIndows 7 + Server 2012?

Comment: You are going to have to wait for Windows to create the profile on the PC no matter what method you use.  You can either use roaming profiles so the user has a single profile, or 30 individual profiles, but either way the intial login will take a few moements.

Comment: User profile creation is very slow, but once done login timing is acceptable, particularly if the computer is not part of a domain. Once the computer is part of a domain, network woes may afflict the computer responsiveness. It used to be so, years ago. So the question is: what is the best way to manage so many users (same profile) on multiple pcs? Roaming profiles?

Comment: There is no way to create the same profile, accross 30 machines, without using roaming profile.  Even if the username is the same, the profile on the machine, itself will be unique.  You can transfer the data from profile to profile, using the tool of your choice that does that, but the will still be seperate identiies.  What does this question have to do with a computer not connected to domain, your network based on your description, part of a domain.

Comment: The appealing part of roaming profiles is the desktop and personals settings being accessible from any PC.

Comment: An alternative to Roaming Profiles is Folder Redirection. The difference is that with Folder Redirection, the profiles are on a network share instead of being downloaded/uploaded to/from the client.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not certain that's particularly necessary, nor are roaming profiles, really depending on what exactly you want.

If you simply want 60 people to be able to log into any computer, then create a domain (you didn't technically say whether there was one already or not), add the 30 PCs to the domain, setup AD, give the users AD accounts, and do it that way.

If you want their full profile data (AppData, etc.) to follow them from PC to PC, then you will need to use roaming profiles.

If you only want their files accessible from each computer, give them a network share folder of their own and set group policy to auto-map it or add it to their AD profile, setting folder permissions appropriately.

A little more context and details about what the exact requirements and goals are would help give you a more precise answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't much of an answer, perhaps just a long wounded comment of "please supply more info"

Comment: Basically users have been used to power on the notebook and start using (no login required), however now that a file serve will be setup, each user will have it's own shared folder/space on the server. This will require creating all the profiles in the AD and then configure the laptops accordingly. Each user should have the opportunity to access the shared folders using the easiest way without clogging each computer. Ideally there could be a single account on each client pc and accessing shared resources would require credentials. Logout would ensure credentials caching being flushed

Comment: You shouldn't have to configure each device.  All you have to do is add the machine to the domain once.  This will allow any user, to log into that device, although their profile will have to be created that first time.  You mount network drives by using a group policy.

Comment: Roaming profiles plus folder redirection seems to be the way to go!